# How to change color of text in c3.js charts?

Tags: css, charts, c3.js

I am using c3.js to create line and bar charts.I want to change the color of x axis and y axis values. As I want black background for the chart so the text/values color on x-axis and y-axis must be white to be visible.
I have tried using the css below but it doesnt work.

```
#chart .c3-text
        {

        color: white;
        }

 #chart c3-axis-axis
        {
        color:white;

        }
#chart c3-text
        {
        color:white;
        }
```

is there a way to change the color of text on chart?

**EDIT**
html code:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </center>

    <script src="../../css/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../../css/c3.js"></script>
    <script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
//       alert("in ajax");

          $.ajax({

                type : "post", 
                url : "../../GetMonthlyTickets",

                success : function(result) {
                var critical = result.critical;
                var warning = result.warning;
                var notif = result.notification;

                critical.unshift("Critical");
                warning.unshift("Warning");
                notif.unshift("Notification");



                var chart = c3.generate({
                    data: {
                         x: 'x',

                        columns: [
                             ['x', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01','2015-07-01', '2015-08-01'],
                             critical,
                             warning,
                             notif
                        ],
                        onclick: function (d, element) { console.log("onclick", d, element); },
                        onmouseover: function (d) { console.log("onmouseover", d); },
                        onmouseout: function (d) { console.log("onmouseout", d); },
                    },

                    color: {
                        pattern: ['#FF0000', '#FFCC00', '#33CC33']
                    },

                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            label: 'Tickets',
                            type: 'timeseries',
                            height: 20,
                                tick: {
                                    fit: true,
                                    format: "%b"                   //format: "%e %b %y"

                                }

                        },
                        y: {
                            label: 'Score'
                        }
                    },

                    grid: {
                        x: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        y: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    },

                    size: {
                        height: 400,
                          width:  1000
                        },

                        zoom:
                        {
                         enabled: true
                        }   

            });             
        }
      });
   });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include your html and the css

Comment: I have included the link of c3.css downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/releases/tag/0.4.10)  in my code.I have added the above lines under a separate style tag to override. I'll post my  html in the edit.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change text color by applying the below CSS lines, including managing font size as well:

```css
.c3-axis-y text {
   fill: red;
   font-size:12px;
}
.c3-axis-x text {
    font-size:12px;
    fill:purple;
}
```

and here is the working demo code for that you can check it out.

**[Running DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/514/)**

Comment: @JEECoder hi check out the answer

Comment: Himesh Aadeshara - thanks for ur answer. I'll let u know after applying.

Comment: @JEECoder welcome, feeling happy to help you :D , if you like you can just upvote the answer